# Facebook Graph API Explorer ERROR

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to visit https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to get the Access token but it results in a blank page after login.

I checked my javascript settings and it works. and this is what the code shows up

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" id="facebook" class="no_js">
<head><meta charset="utf-8" /><script>function envFlush(a){function b(c){for(var d in a)c[d]=a[d];}if(window.requireLazy){window.requireLazy(['Env'],b);}else{window.Env=window.Env||{};b(window.Env);}}envFlush({"ajaxpipe_token":"AXgdFbT1Rp0aBK8L","lhsh":"tAQH6o3p8","khsh":"0`sj`e`rm`s-0fdu^gshdoer-0gc^eurf-3gc^eurf;1;enbtldou;fduDmdldourCxO`ld-2YLMIuuqSdptdru;qsnunuxqd;rdoe"});</script><script>CavalryLogger=false;</script><noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?_fb_noscript=1" /></noscript><meta name="referrer" content="origin-when-crossorigin" id="meta_referrer" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yl/r/gt5mWGlG_pB.css" data-bootloader-hash="rA/VQ" data-permanent="1" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yc/r/IkpzJsYKwmP.css" data-bootloader-hash="5UgiP" data-permanent="1" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/ye/r/R-bPKX7_x2Q.css" data-bootloader-hash="+HR0R" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yd/r/pfQnVrY7nv6.css" data-bootloader-hash="wfuVa" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y_/r/ISKd8C_3w0X.css" data-bootloader-hash="sKrvb" />
<script src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yr/r/0WxISPSMfZk.js" data-bootloader-hash="KMy+E" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Update**
Looks like its happening only when i log into my account. I tested it via a different account and it loads. Any idea how i can get it to work on my dev account of facebook.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question; it should be directed at Facebook support.

Comment: Contact Facebook Support to have them troubleshoot your issues.

Comment: try call logout method and then login again